# Test-retest reliability in R and changes in score of the individuals

Tags: r, biostatistics, reliability

64 cows, subjectivelly tested for chute score response in 2021, by one observer; from score 1 (calm response) to score 4 (nervous response). The same test in 2022, same observer, same animals.  Test-retest reliability was found to be poor, ICC=.35, p<0.00019, 95%CI, .067 to 0.57. So, the test is not consistent over time. But now I want to create 2 groups regarding the response from 2021: group 1 (calm animals, scores 1&2) and group 2 (nervous animals, scores 3&4). My hypothesis is that temperamental cattle acclimate more substantially to repeated handling, meaning their score should drop more than for calm animals. Any ideas how can I test this?

ICC test
..
..
..
..

Comment: Welcome to SO, Madalina Mincu! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: This is assuming that you have a question on _programming_, the premise for StackOverflow. if you have questions about how to analyze something, what tests are appropriate, or something more theoretical, then the question is more appropriate for [stats.se], though they will likely still need more details than you've provided here. Good luck!

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you assumed less knowledge and added less detail for the reader. The fact that the score is a chut score response is irrelevant (and adds confusion). You use the word 'temperamental' in your hypothesis, but not earlier. I don't know what that means (in this context).

Comment: I think your question is that you have scores on two occasions (T1 and T2). There is change in the scores. You think that individuals with high scores at T1 will have larger differences between T1 and T2?

Comment: Hi Jeremy! thanks for the reply! I will try to formulate better. Current methods to evaluate temperament in production settings include numerous subjective measurements such as chute score. Chute score is a restrained technique in which cattle are individually restrained in the chute and scored on a 1 to 4 scale according to their behavior in increments of 1 from (1 – calm to 4 – extremely reactive). Cows were classified as either 'calm' (scores 1 & 2) or 'nervous' (scores 3 & 4). Chute score was undertaken by a single observer over two distinct years (Sept. 2021 & Sept. 2022), on 64 animals.

Comment: The aim was to determine whether cows’ temperament remains stable over time, testing the reliability of the chute score (subjective measure) and investigating habituation to handling in adult cattle.

Comment: I used: test-retest reliability (intra-class correlation) for the chute score response: poor reliability (ICC2 = 0.28, p < 0.0082, 95% CI: 0.052 to 0.49). And linear mixed-effects model (post hoc test): significant difference in the scores change between 'nervous' and 'calm' animals (-1.57±0.27, p < 0.0001) with a modest increase in score for calm animals (0.37±0.18) and a substantial decrease in nervous animals (-1.19±0.19). I'm just wondering if I applied the proper tests. Thanks!